# USB Mount and Software Centre Issues - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, package-management, software-installation, usb, software-uninstall

Using Ubuntu 18.04, but have the following issues on my environment:

1. Ubuntu software center does not work properly;
2. USB device partition hasn't been made automatically during the installation;

Comment: Hi @Aspirant, can you elaborate on the software center not working correctly? I'd just go ahead and perform (from the CLI): `sudo apt update -y` and also `sudo apt upgrade -y` to get started. To open the terminal, use `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T`.

Comment: "USB device partition hasn't been made automatically during the installation" - On Ubuntu, you *should* have 'Partition Manager' as a GUI, this should help you make the partitions you require.